# Display date suggestions as dd/mm/yyyy or DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: input-fields, dates

I have found a lot of posts regarding how to display the order of a date (MM/DD/YYYY vs DD/MM/YYYY) but I haven't found any regarding how to display a "This is how your date should look" hint to a user. Below is an example of how I am currently displaying this hint to a user.

[image]

I am wondering if there is some sort of standard regarding how to display this hint to a user? Or if I can do whatever I like as long as I am consistent throughout my project?

All lower case:

> dd/mm/yyyy mm/dd/yyyy mmyyyy ddmmyyyy

All upper case:

> DD/MM/YYYY MM/DD/YYYY MMYYYY MMDDYYYY

Capital month:

> dd/MM/yyyy MM/dd/yyyy MMyyyy ddMMyyyy

Displaying inconsistently, but may be visually appealing for its condition

> dd/mm/yyyy mm/dd/yyyy MMYYYY ddMMyyyy

Comment: Welcome! I suppose you did research here for similar asked questions, like recommended by: [ask]. What did you found? Which most commonly suggested _date-format_ did you encounter? Why do already answered questions not apply to your context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would *definitely* include the slashes if your input field has them too. It must look at much as valid input as possible. Developers need to worry about the difference between `M` (usually months) and `m` (usually minutes), but not your users.

> Or if I can do whatever I like as long as I am consistent throughout my project

Yes, consistency is important. All lower case seems (to me) to be more readable than all upper case, so I would go with `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy` in your case (depending on the locale of your users).

That said, have you considered a [date picker](https://www.google.com/search?&q=date+picker)? It's excellent for casual users who don't want to be bothered about date formats; if you keep the option open to just type the date, power users will be happy as well.

Answer (score 1):

Three principles to respect:

1. **Consistency**: your UI should be as intuitive as possible, following existing patterns (localized date-format), conventions (common abbreviations for date-parts) and input elements (date-picker)
2. **Use clear language**: instead of hints with syntax, explain by *example*:

   > Enter the date in format `dd/mm/yyyy`. Example: for *28th December 2021* enter `28/12/2021`
3. **Adapt to your target users**: if user is a developer a syntax-oriented input might suffice like `dd/MM/yyyy` whereas non-technical users might be used to and even expecting a date-picker to select a date graphically. Some support like default *prefilled* with today's date or  *auto-completion* may further enhance usability.

#### See also

- [Date and time format placeholders](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/57520/132146)
- [How should I format my Date field Helper Text?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/113253/how-should-i-format-my-date-field-helper-text)
- [Gaceful alternate to consistency in date entry](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/88754/gaceful-alternate-to-consistency-in-date-entry)